# Ruby: return value or nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, return-value, null

I have this method in Rails and it trips up when passed in parameter, `date_string`, is `nil`. Specifically when `GetFileInfo -d` returns nil.

What's a Rails-y way to handle this?

```
def calling_method
  ...
  m = MyModel.create(creation_date: cdate_for(path))
  ...
end

def cdate_for(path)
  local_datetime_for(`GetFileInfo -d "#{path}"`.chomp!)
end

def local_datetime_for(date_string)
  t = Time.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S') 
  DateTime.parse(t.to_s)
end
```

It's OK to return nil from this, assuming `Model.create(creation_date: return_value_here)` can handle nil values.

**Edit:** added some other methods to illustrate call chain.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.blank?`:

```
def local_datetime_for(date_string)
  return nil if date_string.blank?
  t = Time.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S') 
  DateTime.parse(t.to_s)
end
```

---

Some use cases for `.blank?`:

```
1.9.3p448 :042 > false.blank?
 => true 
1.9.3p448 :043 > true.blank?
 => false 
1.9.3p448 :044 > [].blank?
 => true 
1.9.3p448 :045 > ''.blank?
 => true 
1.9.3p448 :046 > '1'.blank?
 => false 
1.9.3p448 :047 > nil.blank?
 => true
```

(For the record, `.present?` is the exact opposite of `.blank?`)

Answer (score 1):

I think idiomatic Ruby calls for this:

```
def local_datetime_for(date_string)
  unless date_string.blank?
    t = Time.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S') 
    DateTime.parse(t.to_s)
  end
end
```

Or if you want to be fancy:

```
def local_datetime_for(date_string)
    DateTime.parse(Time.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S').to_s) unless date_string.blank?
end
```

Using `return` early in the method is very Ruby too. I just have trouble getting used to it coming from a Java background where I avoided early `return`s like the plague.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`File.stat`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File/Stat.html) instead of calling out to the system for `GetFileInfo`. Then handle any exceptions with the `stat` in Ruby that might have caused a `nil` result.

```
def cdate_for(path)
  File.stat(path).ctime.to_datetime
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a condition to check if the date_string is nil or not. I would use a simple If statement,

```
def local_datetime_for(date_string)
  if date_string === nil
    t = Time.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    t = DateTime.parse(t.to_s)
  else
    t = 'Unknown'
  end
  return t
end
```

Comment: added some other methods to illustrate the call chain. Trying to avoid wrapping things in `if` statements. Doesn't feel very "Rails-y"... perhaps I'm over thinking...

Comment: @MrYoshiji 's answer using return nil if looks perhaps a little more "rubish". Also I know the code above is just a sample but just in case it is a copy of the code, I would recommend including "return"s

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `date_string` value immediately. Returning immediately is the best way to express your intent – and use the `nil?` method to express what you're looking for in a Ruby-ish way:

```
def local_datetime_for(date_string)
  return if date_string.nil?
  t = Time.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S') 
  DateTime.parse(t.to_s)
end
```

Expressing the return case in a single "guard clause" is good practice – it gets the edge cases out of the way as quickly as possible, rather than leaving them hanging around like a bad smell, hovering over the meat of the method.